# Which functional specifications are most important in an audio interface?

Tags: recording, sound, effects

I want to buy an external sound card, and I have two choices (because others are crazy expensive here)

- Line6 POD Studio GX
- M-Audio M-Track

I want to be able to connect my guitar and midi keyboard, record, and be able to play live, but I'm not sure what features I should compare.

Should I look at latency, operating system compatibility, etc?

Or which values should I look at in the specs?